# Do I Still Need A Cache Plugin e.g. W3 Total Cache or WP Super Cache etc. To SpeedUp WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, memcached, browser-cache, mod-pagespeed, w3-total-cache

On an Ubuntu 18.04 Machine With Apache2,

I'm using **mod_pagespeed** with default settings except 2 options.

I've installed memcached and enabled the following in "/etc/apache2/mods-available/pagespeed.conf" by removing "**#**"

1. **ModPagespeedMemcachedServers localhost:11211**
2. **ModPagespeedCreateSharedMemoryMetadataCache "/var/cache/mod_pagespeed/" 51200**

My question is, do I still need a plugin e.g. Autoptimize, W3TC, WP Super Cache and etc. to cache, minify etc. etc.?

Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Cache Plugins in general:
Like alway the world is divided into those who love them and those who curse them.

Ask yourself, if you **should** use them?
Is there any benefit for your page?
That depends on the page. Noone can decide that for you.

Helpful are some seo tools - e.g. [Google PageSpeed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?hl=en).

Disable all cache plugins and *check your page speed*.
Sometimes a page is blown up with many plugins generating tons of code (sad to say not rare duplicated and included twice or more times).

Check your plugins and also check your page (frontend) with the developer tools.
Mostly there are many loads you do not really need.

You mentioned

> minify etc.

You can do that by yourself (e.g. with [Brackets](http://brackets.io/) and the minifier plugin or online on mifier pages).
Even the includes for most of the plugins can be minified.

The intention:
Check your page and optimize it. If it not really needs the cache plugins for some functionallity or an high increase of page speed - why use them?

Comment: Thanks For Your Kind Reply, I am running two WordPress installations. One with Mod_Pagespeed + Memcached and The Other With Mod_Pagespeed + Memcached + W3TC.. In Google Pagespeed Test, the installation without W3TC has scored 90 while with W3TC the score is 84.

Comment: Also use other sites to check your speed (e.g. https://gtmetrix.com/).
Relying on one tool only, sometimes is misleading.
Have a look at the page by yourself. When the cache plugin is not making it "smarter", than what benefit has it - if not really necessary for some functionality.